# solution different using a for loop with two increments php

Tags: php

I need print this:

```
l
li
lik
like
lik
li
l
```

but using a for loop with two increments! well basically i was doin' this way!

```
$word = 'like';

for($i=0,$j=7;$i<7;$i++,$j--){
    print substr($word, 0,$i)."<br>";
}
```

it's wrong haha, can u help me?

Comment: Your adding and taking away at the same time..

Comment: homework?? this exist? its doesn't my homework, just a question!

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to clean this code up a bit, but the best way, as far as I can tell is the following:

Loop through the characters in the string, adding the previous letters where applicable, adding them to an array. You can then remove the duplicate string of the `$word` using `array_pop` which removes the last object from the array. From there, you need to make a copy of the array in reverse using `array_reverse()`, and then `implode()` causing the array to turn to a string. The `<br />` is used so that each string in the array will be printed on a new line.

I don't particularly care whether this is your homework or not, as suggested by @Madara Uchiha, but it is merely helping me further my knowledge of PHP.

```
$word = "like";

$order = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        $order[] = $word[$i];
    }
    else {
        $str = "";
        for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {
            $str .= $word[$j];
        }
        $order[] = $str;
    }
}

$backwards = array_reverse($order);
array_pop($order);
$string = implode("<br />", array_merge($order, $backwards));
echo $string;
```

Comment: No need to use `preg_split`. `$string[$index]` works fine.

Comment: i want to use a for loop with 2 variables

Answer (score 0):

```
$word = 'like';

for($i = 0, $x = $cnt = strlen($word); $i <= $cnt*2; $i++){
    if($i <= $cnt)
        print substr($word, 0,$i)."<br>";
    else
        print substr($word, 0, --$x)."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Here, the number of times `for` loop should run, is one less than 2*length of the word.
2. The number of characters printed, goes on increasing until you print the whole word once, then it starts decreasing.

So the code becomes:

```
    $word = 'like';
    $length = strlen($word);

    for($i=1, $j=1; $i < ($length*2) ; $i++ )
    {
        print substr($word, 0, $j)."<br>";
        if($i < $length)
            $j++;
        else
            $j--;
    }
```

**A few tips:**

1. Avoid constants as much as you can in your programs. (You used a 7 in your code which breaks when input word the changes!)
2. Try practicing some pattern printing questions! :-)